# Using a html form to input a twitter id and return the recent statuses using ajax and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, twitter

I am trying to print the recent tweets of a twitter account on a page using a html text feild to input the user id. So far i can send the user id to a PHP page that gets the tweets and prints them.

I am able to connect to the twitter api with php and print out the recent tweets. I need to be able to print the tweets back on my original page. 
Also I need ajax to keep requesting the php to acces the twitter api so as after the user submits the twitter id it will update without refreshing.

here is the html form that links to the php:

```
<form name="input" action="twitterTest2.php" method="get">Twitter Username: 
  <input type="text" name="userid">
  <input type="submit" value="Get recent Tweets">
</form>
```

here is the php that gets the tweets from twitter:

```
<?php
  function getTwitterStatus()
  {
    $userid = $_GET['userid'];
    //url that accesses the twitter api for statuses xml
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/$userid.xml?count=5";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("could not connect");
    foreach ($xml->status as $status) {
      $text = $status->text;
      echo $text;
    }
  }
  getTwitterStatus();
?>
```

Comment: Replace the form with AJAX, and have the PHP format it as JSON for the ajax to interpret.

Comment: I need to have it as XML though. Can you look at my ajax functions below? I'm not sure what is going wrong with them. I have specified a 'showtext' area in the html for the tweets to print.

Comment: its ok, i worked it out. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    /** Create a cross-browser XMLHttp Request object. **/
    function getXMLHttp() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
}
     //function that searches for the tweets  via php
     function getStatuses(){

   XMLHttp1 = getXMLHttp();

      //ajax call to a php file that will search  the tweets
       XMLHttp1.open( 'GET', 'twitterTest2.php', true);

  // Process the data when the ajax object changes its state
       ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if( ajax.readyState == 4 ) {
           if ( ajax.status ==200 ) {  //no problem has been detected

  response = XMLHttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("showText").value = response;

      }
}
  }
}

/** Check for response and update the text-area. **/
function updateInfo() { 
    if(xmlhttp1.readyState == 4) { 
        response=XMLHttp1.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showText").value = response;

    } 
}

</script>
```